# Power Automate DesktopでOutlookが起動できないとエラーが出る

Tags: windows

Outlook側の設定が出来ていないのか、ブラウザで検索しても対処方法が分からない為教えてください。
まったくの初心者でこんな質問してしまい、すみません。

[image: エラー画面]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自信はありませんが当てずっぽうで。

Outlookは既に実行中の状態でフローを実行しましたでしょうか？

- 他のOfficeアプリケーションと異なりOutlookは複数プロセスを起動できません。
- Power Automate Desktopは管理下に置くため自身で起動したプロセスを扱うようです。

そのため、既に実行中の場合にPower Auotmate Desktopからは起動できずに質問のようなエラーが発生する可能性はあります。

Comment: お返事が遅くなり申し訳ございません。ご回答ありがとうございます！！丁寧にご回答いただけて大変助かりました。ありがとうございました！